# make calls to firestore with auth-rules

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I recently changed the firestore rules to the following rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

This should only allow authenticated users to access firestore. I'm using react-native as the frontend framework and it signs the user in anonymously if the user isn't already logged in. So all the requests going to firestore are from an authenticated user(anonymous or logged-in). **However, after I updated the rules, the app isn't fetching anything from firestore. Are there any changes that must be done in the frontend after updating firestore rules?**

[UPDATE] react-native throws me this error: `FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Comment: If you log the user's UID in the client just before making the request, does it verify that a user is actually logged in?

Comment: Can you update your question to show the minimal, complete, standalone code that we can run to reproduce the problem? See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You've got an extra match statement in there that's messing things up. If you just want all your authenticated users to have full read, write access to your full Firestore database, you'd just use:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
  }
}
```

Comment: removed the extra match statement but the app still throws me `FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.` error

Comment: My apologies. Your initial rules were correct. (I should have double-checked.) I tested your rules in a sample database and found they *do* work for authenticated Anonymous users since they're issued a uid.

Comment: You said the problem started after updating the rules. What rules were you using previously? Just open "Allow all" rules?

Comment: yes, earlier the rules were set to 'open'. `if true;`. You said that you tried it out yourself and they did work for authenticated users, right? What changes did you make to the `firebase.firestore().get()/post()` methods?

Comment: I validated the rules using the Simulator on the Firebase console Rules page. Simulating a user authenticated anonymously, it showed I was successfully able to Get a document from a collection. Your rules are good.

Comment: Does your first Firestore access follow a ".signInAnonymously" or is it following an ".onAuthStateChanged" trigger? I ask because it sounds like your app may be trying to hit Firestore before authentication is complete.

Comment: || this is the flow of the app right now: `.onAuthStateChanged()` is called > if the user obj returned is null, `.signInAnonymously()` is called > else the user object is cached in locally. All the firestore calls happen after this flow.

Comment: That should be fine as long as your `.onAuthStateChanged()` observer function exits after the call to `.signInAnonymously()` bypassing the firestore calls.